# Asp.Net:Light ajax (get) call that doesn't rerender the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

Let say I have:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnNoticeClose" runat="server" 
 ImageUrl="~/img/btn_spara_green.gif" ToolTip="Stäng" 
 OnClientClick="jQuery('#Notice').hide();" 
 Click="btnNoticeClose_Click"/>
```

How do I call a btnNoticeClose_Click without rerendering anything? As I don't need to rerender anything I don't want to use an UpdatePanel? or do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
 OnClientClick="jQuery('#Notice').hide();return null;"
```

or write full function in js:

```
function CloseThis()
{
    $("#Notice").hide();
    return true;
}

 OnClientClick="javascript:CloseThis();"
```

EDIT:- Well you want to call server side method as well and don't want to render anything. Then only option left is using page method and using jQuery AJAX. Please head [here to Dave's](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) blog for more information on this.

Comment: Well, ok. but I aktually want to call btnNoticeClose_Click as well?